# saving the state of page and retrieving it back to the same state

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, session, model-view-controller

My question is plain and simple.

I have a jsp page (home.jsp) where i give a form to user to search for sales information. Once the user enters the form with the details he wants to know and hits on search button. My javascript validates if the user inputs are good, then it sends the user values in the form of json(using $.POST,m used to jquery) to the controller, where i use a dao to query the database and return the results(again in the form of json). I populated these returned values from db in the form of a table.

Now, the problem is, when user hits search and suppose he goes to another page in the application(history.jsp) and comes back to (home.jsp) using back button in the browser(IE to be specific). I want the search results to be as it is.

But they are not. I need to somehow save the entire values in the form(input boxes,drop downs,radio buttons) and the search results as it is. How can i accomplish this.

You would say session, but (home.jsp) uses a combination of both javascript ajax call and controller (spring mvc) to get search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage for keeping form data: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: hi isn't this the feature of html5?